# CSS style applies to all cases?

Tags: html, css

```
#menu {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; width:100%; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
#menu li {display:list-item; float:left;}
#menu a:link,a:visited {border-right:1px solid #BBBBBB; display:block; float:left;  padding:10px 15px; color:#AAAAAA; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear;}
#menu a:hover,a:active {background-color:#0096FF; color:#FFFFFF; -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear;}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id='header'>
<a href='index.html'><img src='logo.png' /></a>
</div>
<ul id='menu'>
<li><a href='index2.html'>HOME</a></li>
<li><a href='index.html'>FORUM</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, that I have another link BEFORE the UL which also gains these properties. How would I make so only the links inside the UL gets these properties and not the link before (outside the UL).

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
#menu a:link,#menu a:visited {border-right:1px solid #BBBBBB; display:block; float:left;   padding:10px 15px; color:#AAAAAA; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; -webkit-transition:  background 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear;}
#menu a:hover,#menu a:active {background-color:#0096FF; color:#FFFFFF; -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear;}
```

you forgot to Put #menu before a:visited and a:active